# Datatypes and screwy results PHP/C#/WinForms

Tags: c#, php, .net, mysql, winforms

I am having a lot of issues with the Decimal datatype in PHP and WinForms (C#). See, I have built a website and an Order and inventory management app for a client, but often the values will get all screwy. And I'm interested in how *you* handle pricing, discounts, freight. Do you use float, double decimal?

I swear, I had less troubles when I first started learning PHP and used VARCHAR for pricing! (And I'm not exagerating)

In my clients database, let's say I have the following:

```
Column Name     Column Name     Column Name     Column Name  
Price           Quantity         Discount        LineTotal
```

ALl columns are of the decimal datatype, except for Quantity. Quantity column is int.

And when I'm doing very basic calculations, like:

```
$LineTotal = $Price * $Quantity;
```

I get stupid results, like this:

```
5.98888
7.
9.111
0.4442
```

And, worst of all, often it will just completely remove numbers from the calculation:

If for example the result of a multiplication is (or *should be*): `4.92`

I'll go have a look in the database, and it'll say: `4`

Where's my `.92` cents?

What can be causing this? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: how many decimal places did you specify for your `decimal` type? probably you didn't specify number of digits to the right of the decimal point that's why it's always a whole number e.g. just `4` instead of `4.92`

Comment: In C# place "m" after variable to cast it as decimal. Like 4.656M * 343.2456M... After you get result, make it more precise with only two digits after "."

Comment: Why are those results "stupid"?  Are you under some impression that the result of a multiplication will always return a result with a certain number of decimal places?  Perhaps you might this [Floating Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/) useful.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no decimal type support in PHP. So the question is probably about what type really is in `$LineTotal`, `$Price` and `$Quantity` variables. Consider investigation using: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php

Answer (score -2):

Umm I'm not sure about PHP but when I had weird stuff happening as well when I used decimal types and C#. So I just use double now.

Comment: -1 That's hardly a better solution than attempting to understand the type that's giving you (and the OP) problems.

Comment: It wasn't a solution, he said he was intersted in how we handle pricing, discounts and etc.